# Ubuntu: Configuring Xdebug (PHP) for Eclipse 3.2

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, eclipse-plugin, xdebug

I have installed Eclipse 3.2 in my ubuntu system.

I have added the php plugin to eclipse by following steps
    Help > Software Updates > Find and Install.. > selected "Search for new features to install" and clicked "NEXT" > clicked "New Remote Site" > Gave name = "PHP" and url = "http://update.phpeclipse.net/update/nightly" > Clicked "Finish"

Now, I am trying to configure XDebug as in the steps below
    Windows > Preferences.. > PHP Eclipse > selected "XDebug" and given appropriate port number and php path ( /usr/bin/php ) > Clicked "OK"

Next selected "Run" > "Debug" then opened a window named "Debug"

In that, when i double clicked  "PHP XDebug Remote Script", I got an error dialog box saying "An error has occured. See error log for more details"

```
Error Log:

Message : "Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface"."

Exception stack trace: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path for project must have only one segment.
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isLegal(Assert.java:63)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.WorkspaceRoot.getProject(WorkspaceRoot.java:181)
at net.sourceforge.phpeclipse.xdebug.ui.php.launching.PHPRemoteDebug.isValid(PHPRemoteDebug.java:166)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.refresh(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:532)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.updateButtons(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1425)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.refreshStatus(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1160)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.refreshStatus(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:989)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer$8.run(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:692)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.inputChanged(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:697)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput0(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:659)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.setInput(LaunchConfigurationTabGroupViewer.java:635)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.handleLaunchConfigurationSelectionChanged(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:916)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog$3.selectionChanged(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:544)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:864)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:888)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:862)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1200)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:245)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$3.run(OpenStrategy.java:419)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3468)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3115)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationsDialog.open(LaunchConfigurationsDialog.java:1064)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools$1.run(DebugUITools.java:398)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup(DebugUITools.java:406)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.DebugUITools.openLaunchConfigurationDialogOnGroup(DebugUITools.java:340)
at org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.OpenLaunchDialogAction.run(OpenLaunchDialogAction.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1176)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3493)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3112)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

Can any one help me out with this problem...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

See tutorial 
path bin for xdebuger not add

http://www.rdeeson.com/weblog/102/installing-xdebug-for-use-with-eclipse-on-ubuntu-linux.html
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Debugging_using_XDebug